# Is there a way to get the name of the generic type in a generic (<T>) function/class (Typescript)?

Tags: javascript, generics, typescript

Here is the definition of my function:

```
getData<T extends Entity> () { }
```

I don't currently accept any arguments. Is there a way for me to translate the T into the string name of the type at runtime? Perhaps using typeof?

I am from the C# world where you would use reflection. However I am new to Javascript and not sure what the equivalent would be.

Thanks.

Comment: If there are no arguments then why do you need the type there?

Comment: I will need to compose a url string, part of which is the name of the class T. And I will return an object of a generic type: for instance, Result<T>.

Comment: Perhaps override of `toString()` method could help?

Answer (score 5):

Types are erased during compilation, so no. You should *never* ***ever*** have a generic function that doesn't use its type parameter in an argument position.

Assuming `getData` works on classes, you could write something like:

```
class NotSureThisIsReallyAGoodIdea {
    static getData<T>(cls: new(...args: any[]) => T): T {
        /* magic happens */
        const url = 'http://example.com/' + cls['name'];
        return <T>undefined;
    }
}

class SomeShape {
    x: number;
}

let s = NotSureThisIsReallyAGoodIdea.getData(SomeShape);
s.x; // OK
```

Comment: This worked for me, thank you.

    getData<T extends Entity>(type: { new(): T ;} ) {
       let d = new type();
       let name: string = d.getName();
    }

(not sure how to format code sample)